# jpa spring-test flush error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, spring-test

I have table `Product` with field like that in my database:

```
@Transient
private Map<Locale, String> description = new HashMap<>();
```

`description` is defined in class `ProductLocalization`.

After i added `columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT"` to

```
@Column(name = Product.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private String description;
```

in that class I'm able to set descriptions longer than 255 marks as I wanted, but 2 of my tests started to fail in lines before `productDao.saveAndFlush(product)` at `product.setDescription(descriptions)`, important can be that when I do that operation in application, not in test everything works fine, only test cause problems

`saveAndFlush()` is method i got from package `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository`

Error is the same in both tests:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PRODUCT_LOCALIZED
Error Code: -5501
Call: INSERT INTO product_localized (description, entity_id, language) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [angielski, 3, en]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(ProductLocalization{description=angielski})
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:804)
```

Here's code of tests:

```
 @Test
public void testMultilingualCreate() {
    // Given
    String polish = "polski", english = "angielski";
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("Product name");
    Map<Locale, String> descriptions = new HashMap<>(); 
    descriptions.put(Locale.ENGLISH, english);
    descriptions.put(Messages.POLISH, polish);

    // When
    product.setDescription(descriptions);
    Product p = productDao.saveAndFlush(product);
    product = productDao.findOne(p.getId());

    // Then
    assertEquals(polish, product.getDescription(Messages.POLISH));
    assertEquals(english, product.getDescription(Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

and

```
@Test
public void testMultilingualUpdate() {
    // Given
    String polish = "polski", english = "angielski", english2 = "another english description";
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("Product name");
    Map<Locale, String> descriptions = new HashMap<>(); 
    descriptions.put(Locale.ENGLISH, english);
    descriptions.put(Messages.POLISH, polish);

    // When
    product.setDescription(descriptions);
    product = productDao.saveAndFlush(product);
    assertEquals(english, product.getDescription(Locale.ENGLISH));
    descriptions.put(Locale.ENGLISH, english2);
    product.setDescription(descriptions);
    product = productDao.saveAndFlush(product);

    // Then
    assertEquals(polish, product.getDescription(Messages.POLISH));
    assertEquals(english2, product.getDescription(Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

What is wrong here How can I fix it?

Comment: Is **saveAndFlush** method works fine from application.

Comment: Is that only getting error in **test** method

Comment: @Boss yes, error is only in test method, application works fine

Comment: Could you add saveAndFlush code

Comment: @Boss saveAndFlush() is method i got from package org.springframework.data.jpa.repository

Comment: Since it looks like some configuration issue for me,could you Add the configuration of test class please.. which means the xml files you loaded for the class

Comment: I faced the same issue, and I figured out, that `flush()` method is useless in JUnit tests. I started using just `save()`, and everything became well. I suppose that issue might be in separated-threaded environment of jUnit tests with shared EntityManager instance.